# how to detect change of actual value not just OnChange nuxt vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

As a result of

```
export default {
  name: "Details",
  async asyncData({ redirect, params, store }) {
    if (
      !store
```

I am returning a few values in which one of them is

```
  return {
    camera: c,
    thumbnail_url: thumbnail_url,
```

camera, and then in my form fields where I am populating a `Vuetify` dialog, Text Field inputs

such as

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-layout class="model-container">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" lg="7" md="7" sm="12" xs="12">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="camera.name"
              class="caption bottom-padding"
              required
            >
              <template v-slot:label>
                <div class="caption">
                  Name
                </div>
              </template>
            </v-text-field>
```

my issue is, I have a button as

```
      <v-btn color="primary" text @click="updateCamera">
        Save
      </v-btn>
```

which I only want to make disable `false`, only if there is an actual change occurs to, `this.camera`, in `updateCamera` method, I can use the updated values as

```
async updateCamera() {
  let payload = {
    name: this.camera.name,
```

but I want to enable or disable the button on when change occurs,

I had tried `@input`, I have also tried to watch `camera` object

```
            <v-text-field
              v-model="camera.name"
              class="caption bottom-padding"
              required
              @input="up($event, camera)"
            >
```

This way I tried to get some info about event, such as which text field it is, so I can compare, but in up method it only passes input value.

in watch

```
camera: function() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log(this.camera)
  })
}
camera: {
  handler: function(val) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(val)
    })
    /* ... */
  },
  immediate: true
}
```

I have tried this but nothing worked.

Of course, we can enable or disable a button on change but not just if the user places an A and then deletes it, not such change.
Any help would be wonderful

Update:

Even after using this

```
camera: {
  handler: function(newValue) {
    if (newValue === this.dumpyCamera) {
      console.log(this.dumpyCamera)
      console.log(newValue)
      console.log("here")
      this.updateButton = true
    } else {
      this.updateButton = false
    }
  },
  deep: true
}
```

both new and old values are the same.

I have tried to add new variable dumyCamera and on mount I have assigned this.camera value to this.dumyCamera but when something changes in camera, it changes this.dumyCamera as well? why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to recognize any changes made to this.camera by using a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

```
watch: {
  camera: {
    handler (newValue, oldValue) {
      // do something here because your this.camera changed
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Comment: old a new both value are the same. but it does get called

Comment: both newValue oldValue and this.camera are updated one

Comment: @JunaidFarooq have you solved the issue, got the same issue as you